# Hacer UPDATE donde un campo sea igual a otro

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo una pequeña duda que no se como se resuelve correctamente

Tengo una consulta:

```html
SELECT ID, ORDER_ID, QTY_DELIVERED, QUANTITY FROM table WHERE ORDER_ID = '12345'
```

La cual devuelve varios resultados con el `ORDER_ID` **12345**

Y despues, actualizo el campo `QTY_DELIVERED` con el dato que viene en `QUANTITY`:

```html
UPDATE table SET QTY_DELIVERED = QUANTITY WHERE ID = ID;
```

El problema es, que cada resultado del **SELECT** tiene una cantidad distinta

Lo he solucionado haciendo un **while**, pero quería saber si hay alguna solución para que se actualice cada resultado con sus correspondientes datos en una única consulta

> Con while

```html
while ($row = $rs->nextRecord()){
    $query = "UPDATE table SET QTY_DELIVERED = QUANTITY WHERE ID = ID";
}
```

Comment: Por favor especifica que motor de bases de datos usas

Comment: Utilizo el motor MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque estas utilizando mal el where. Deberías utilizarlo así en tu caso:

```
BEGIN TRAN
 UPDATE table 
 SET QTY_DELIVERED = QUANTITY 
 WHERE ORDER_ID = '12345'
```

Si estan ok los cambios cerra la transaccion:

```
 COMMIT TRAN
```

En caso de que no sean los resultados esparados un rollback:

```
 ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Saludos!

Comment: Me causa duda tu sintaxis de la transacción seguro está bien para MySQL?